# Update model value

Tags: django

I need suggestions on how to approach this problem.

Basically I have 3 models

```
class SGrade(TimeStampedModel):
   subject_sched = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSched)
    final_grade = models.DecimalField(max_digit=5)

class SubjectSched(models.Model):
   subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)

class Subject(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=150) 



class Comp(models.Model):
    subj_sched = models.ForeignKey(SubjectSched)
        name = models.Charfield(max_length=150)
        percentage = models.DecimalField(max_digit=5)

class Grade(TimeStampedModel):
    sgrade = models.ForeignKey(SGrade)
        component = models.ForeignKey(Component)
        grade = models.Decimal(max_digits=5)
```

I would like to make an updateview with form for each student's grades. I can access the final grade from SGrade model while the subject name is in Subject model. Grades per component is in Grade model and component (e.g. 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th quarters ) are in Component. I am currently ready about Formset but still getting the grasp of it.

Comment: I can't understand your question exactly.. could you describe more? (or you can add your current updateview) what exactly do you want to do inside updateview - update 'Grade' and 'SGrade' object ? or update all three models' object above?

Comment: My apologies for the confusion. Basically, I have page that displays the student's grades with subjects from 1st Quarter - 4th Quarter. I would like to add a button in this page which will redirect user to a page where he/she can update the grades. Yes, I want to update the Grades and SGrades objects.

Comment: Oh thanks for quick comment. I understand your situation. Well.. there's many choices for you. First, you can simply add view (View in CBV or just fbv is fine) accepting form (with Grade and SGrades values) and manually save it to each model. It's pretty simple and instinctive. 
Second, you can use 'UpdateView' with one model - maybe 'Grade' model - and when saving (form_valid) - you can edit 'SGrade' object related to grade object. Which way do you prefer?

Comment: I want to do the UpdateView approach. Shall I use formset for this? Grade has a foreignkey to SGrade while SGrade has a foreignkey to Subject which contains the subject names. I just need to display the subject name in the updateview then I should be able to update the grades per subject. I updated the post as well so you can see the models.